# Civicontribute: Missing payemnt options when required field missing or back button

Tags: contribution-page, 4.6.6

I've hit some strange behavior on a contribution page.  I consider payment usability a big issue.

Using a price set, have radio select for different donation amounts (need price set as different financial types).  Also have an "Other" numeric field.  Payment options has 2 choices: "pay by cc" or "pay by check".

This is a common use case.  Unless you add an explicit "other" in the select list with a 0 value, the option list will show "none" as an option.

Setting a radio select field with numeric value >0 works correctly.
Setting a text / numeric input value >0 works correctly.

Setting a radio with a select numeric = 0 AND a text numeric value > 0 will not present the payment options but will increment the total.

Further problems when field does not validate on page or hitting back button - payment processor selection does not appear.

I see lot's of cc related issues but not this one please let me know if this is a known bug or a new one...

Comment: Tried to use webform, but does not seem to support "other" amount or multiple payment fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see a specific issue but this looks fixed in latest template file: http://bit.ly/1NecugN